Numbers 13.1 - How to pull an entire row from another sheet
Basically, how to i make it act more like FileMaker Pro did way back when?
i have a file with greyhound pedigrees; each dog has a different sheet. What i'd like to do is NOT have to repeatedly enter the same dogs over and over (go far enough back and you get a lot of repeats). Each row is a dog, a record; each column in an attribute.
In FMP, i could have had the key match to a specific field in another file and pull data in that record over to the first file.
i know this is a spreadsheet, and not a database, but i no longer have access to FMP and whilst i understand the outline of programming this in Python, I can't seem to get the code to work.
When i am working in, say Sheet 2, and reference a row in Sheet 1 [Sheet1::54:54], all i get is the value in A54. i can't seem to get the entire record to populate.
Is this even possible? Or should I be looking at LibreOffice's Calc or Base and see if it will work?
i really miss having access to FMP, but i can't afford to pay what they want now and i don't need all the bells and whistles. Bento was almost enough. i just want to be able to make a simple relational database for myself.

In general, spreadsheets hold values (and functions) in cells; a cell is the intersection of a specific row and a specific column. Databases hold values in records; you can think of a record as a row of cells in a defined table of rows and columns.
To get the effect you want in Numbers or Excel or Calc, your references must be cell-to-cell, rather than rows referenced/related to each other by some shared identifier. And a very important aspect is that, unlike what's possible with databases, spreadsheet cell references are one-way. A reference in cell X to show the value in cell Y does not allow you to modify cell Y by changing cell X - instead if you change cell X, you break its reference to cell Y.
If in Sheet 1 you want a row to show values from a row in Sheet 2, the most basic way in spreadsheets is to have a formula in each cell in the row of Sheet 1 that references the cell in the row of Sheet 2 whose value you want.
Fortunately Numbers and the other spreadsheet apps provide ways to avoid tediously typing formulas in multiple cells. In Numbers take a look at the menu command Table -> Autofill Cells. Once you have the first cell in Sheet 1 correctly showing the cell value you want from Sheet 2, you can extend the reference across the row. There will be a learning curve about cell references, including use or avoidance of the dollar sign ('$') if you're not already familiar with that.
It's possible to build complex interactive applications in Numbers or other spreadsheets, involving multiple files with multiple worksheets. But the work is quite different in detail from that for databases. And some features do not directly translate across the two approaches.
I don't mean to discourage you from attempting to get that you want from Numbers. If your purpose is to have a single editable place for each bit of raw data, with the rest of the spreadsheet providing summaries or calculations from that data, you're good.
For example, to estimate the costs of a mailing, I maintain price tables for factors such as graphic designers, print shops, mailing services, postage rates, etc., which vary by quantity & format. Each cost factor's price table is on its own sheet. Then on an Estimate sheet, I have cells in which I input a quantity, and cells with formulas that multiply that quantity by the appropriate costs in the assorted price tables, and also cells that add those all up to the total costs for the mailing.

Thank you so much, i'll try that Autofill. i've been delighted that a lot of my knowledge of tables and dataframes from python has helped me work out how to do many things in Numbers (and Excel, for work; i refuse to have MS on my laptop!), but there are things i was used to doing that just don't directly translate. Thanks for the tip!
